# Having syntax issues when trying to print a list within a list

Tags: c#, list

I cant quite figure out the syntax on how to get the values of this list within a list.

```
 public class Toppings
 {
    public List<string> PizzaToppings { get; set; }

 }

static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<Toppings> items = new List<Toppings>();

        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("C:\\pizzas.json"))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Toppings>>(json);
        }
```

I've populated my list as shown above but I am not sure how to print. This is one of the many things I've tried:

```
foreach (Toppings item in items)
{
    foreach (List<string> s in item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s.PizzaToppings);
    }   
}
```

But I keep getting errors about not having a public instance definition of "GetNumerator" for "item.

The JSON looks like this

```
[
  {
    "toppings": [
      "pepperoni"
    ]
  },
  {
    "toppings": [
      "feta cheese",
      "bacon"
    ]
  },
```

And when I tried doing foreach (String s in item.PizzaToppings I got an object reference not set to an instance of object error.

Comment: `items` is a collection of `Toppings`. Therefore, `item` is a `Toppings`, which you must know because you declared it that way. Does `Toppings` have a method named `GetEnumerator()`? No. Is `Toppings` in any way a collection of many lists of strings? No. If you want to enumerate the `PizzaToppings` collection in `item`, try `foreach (String s in item.PizzaToppings) { Console.WriteLine(s); }`.

Comment: Please share some of the JSON, in order to help you with the problem.

Comment: Sounds like either `item` or `PizzaToppings` is null. Did you put in a breakpoint and find out which?

Comment: Excellent. Maybe you need to rename `PizzaToppings` to `toppings`. You can't expect the JSON parser to speak English well enough to guess that they're supposed to be the same property.

Comment: @EdPlunkett okay I got it running. PizzaToppings was not matching the JSON Name of toppings. Thank you

Comment: @user1984300 Bingo! One step ahead of me. Top notch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to make sure the object matches the JSON. Also you can do a SelectMany to collapse the list of list. The following code will print out all the toppings in the JSON:

```
void Main()
{
    var json = File.ReadAllText("C:\\pizzas.json");

    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PizzaToppings>>(json);

    foreach(var topping in obj.SelectMany(o => o.Toppings))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(topping);
    }
}

public class PizzaToppings
{
    public List<string> Toppings {get;set;}
}
```